# Python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, system, distributed

How can I know if a node that is being accessed using TCP socket is alive or if the connection was interrupted and other errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Any intermediate nodes can drop your packets or the reply packets from the remote node.

Comment: +1: It's down when you get an EOF or an Exception.  Until then, it's up.